# How to avoid scale_fill_discrete() changed the bar's colors of geom_candlestick

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyquant

I have sample stock price data (in the end of this question) and I am trying to plot the `geom_candlestick` chart and add different background colors for multiple date intervals using the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyquant)
library(lubridate)

data$date <- as.Date(data$date, format='%Y/%m/%d')
rects <- data.frame(
  xstart = as.Date(c('2021/12/1', '2021/12/9'), format = '%Y/%m/%d'),
  xend = as.Date(c('2021/12/8', '2021/12/17'), format = '%Y/%m/%d'),
  col = c('in_period', 'out_period')
)

ggplot(data=data, aes(x = as.Date(date))) +
  geom_candlestick(aes(open = open, high = high, low = low, close = close), alpha=0.6) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = "3 days", date_labels = "%Y-%m-%d") +
  geom_rect(data = rects, aes(xmin = xstart, xmax = xend, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = col), alpha = 0.4, inherit.aes = FALSE)
  # + scale_fill_discrete(name = "Period", label = c('in_period', 'out_period'), limits = c('in_period', 'out_period'))
```

Output:

[image]

I hope to remove extra legend part `darkblue` and `red` while keeping `in_period` and `out_period` only with `scale_fill_discrete(name = "Period", label = c('in_period', 'out_period'), limits = c('in_period', 'out_period'))`.

Then I get a figure below as I uncomment last line of code:

[image]

I successfully removed unwanted legend part, but as you may notice, the candlestick's bar chart become same almost gray color which is different from the figure above.

So my question is how could I remove extra legend part while keeping same color effect as the first plot? Thanks.

Data:

```
data <- structure(list(date = structure(c(18962, 18963, 18964, 18965, 
18966, 18967, 18968, 18969, 18970, 18971, 18972, 18973, 18974, 
18975, 18976, 18977, 18978), class = "Date"), open = c(1360L, 
1333L, 1341L, 1412L, 1452L, 1455L, 1487L, 1510L, 1502L, 1491L, 
1530L, 1520L, 1495L, 1485L, 1507L, 1500L, 1490L), high = c(1360L, 
1349L, 1387L, 1456L, 1467L, 1503L, 1507L, 1552L, 1518L, 1540L, 
1543L, 1532L, 1504L, 1508L, 1528L, 1506L, 1520L), low = c(1334L, 
1316L, 1340L, 1410L, 1425L, 1445L, 1474L, 1506L, 1468L, 1483L, 
1518L, 1488L, 1471L, 1475L, 1498L, 1489L, 1490L), close = c(1334L, 
1344L, 1387L, 1456L, 1458L, 1486L, 1484L, 1515L, 1503L, 1532L, 
1531L, 1489L, 1491L, 1504L, 1505L, 1496L, 1504L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-17L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `breaks` instead of `limits`? (see e.g. [Remove legend entries for some factors levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21801950/remove-legend-entries-for-some-factors-levels))

Comment: If it's numeric, I should use `limits=c()`, otherwise, if it's character, I should use `breaks=c()`, do I understand correctly?

Comment: Please see the answer from this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70517464/error-invalid-input-time-trans-works-with-objects-of-class-posixct-only-for-ge, it works using `limits()`, I don't know why.

Comment: If you want to modify legend entries, I think `breaks` is the right way. The `ggplot` help text may be a bit terse in this respect (yes, I have been struggling too...). You may wish to refer to other tutorials. See e.g. the description of `breaks` [here](https://heima.hafro.is/~einarhj/education/ggplot2/scales.html): "The `breaks` argument controls which values appear as tick marks on axes and keys on legends.". See also the `limits` section in that doc (and other relevant parts). Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. :)